# Identify the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle2x+1,6\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

There goes a theorem which says that an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is maximal if and only if $I$ is of the form $\langle f(x),p\rangle$ where $p$ is a prime and $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo $p$.

Lets consider the ring  $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2x+1,6\rangle$. In this ring we have relations $2x=-1$ so $3=3(-2x)=0$. Hence $3x=x-1=0$. Therefore $x=1$ where $f(x)$ is identified with the equivalent class. We get $R=\left\{0,1,2 \right\}$ so it seems that $R \simeq \mathbb{Z}_3$ which forces $\langle 2x+1,6\rangle$ be a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which should be wrong.

My question is what the ring $R$ actually is and what am I missing.

Comment: $R\cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, just like you say.

Comment: For a simpler example consider the following. We know that all the maximal ideals $M$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ are of the form $M=\langle p\rangle$ with $p$ a prime number. Yet, $I=\langle 4,6\rangle$ is also maximal. There is no contradiction because $$\langle 4,6\rangle=\langle 2\rangle.$$

Comment: Many thanks to comments. I'm aware of that logic. However I did not expected such flexibility of ideal representations in the integer coefficient polynomial ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your correct calculations showed that
$$
\langle 2x+1,6\rangle=\langle x-1,3\rangle
$$
so it seems to me that the ideal **is** of the prescribed form.

The result you stated did not claim that the given form is the **only** way to list a set of generators for that ideal.

Anyway, $R\simeq\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}.$